# Data Retrival from mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I am using the code below to retrieve image data from mysql and show on my webpage. But it's too slow. How can I make it faster?

```
// include database connection 

$connect=mysqli_connect($host,$db_name,$password,$username);
$query="SELECT * FROM images ORDER BY id DESC";
$result=mysqli_query($connect,$query);

while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

 echo '<tr>
    <td>
     <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode($row['image']).'" width="100%" height="100%"/> 
  </td>
 </tr>';

}
```

Comment: Simple: Don't put the image files into your database. More complex: Get a faster web server or ISP.

Comment: You could try storing a path instead of a blob. If the images are large (more than 100k), then this seems like a better idea.

Comment: How do you store image in DB ?

Comment: The ideal way is to store images in a separate location and only store the paths to images in DB. Don't make your DB transactions cost and energy expensive

Comment: i have succesfully moved the images into a separate folder but image paths are not storing in the database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your help.I have moved the images into a different folder named "uploaded" in the server and stored the relative image paths into the database and it's faster and working fine

```
 <?php
   $link=mysqli_connect($host,$db_name,$password,$username);
   $sql="SELECT * FROM images ORDER BY id DESC ";
   $result=mysqli_query($link,$sql);


    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
       {
        $image[] = $row;
       }


     foreach($image as $brand){

         echo"<img src='uploaded/".$brand["name"]."'width=33%,height=33%>";

 }

?>
```

Answer (score -2):

Don't use * .Use only fields which you need amd you can put INDEX in database on fields which you use

Comment: How would an index help when there's no `WHERE` clause?